# Suspicious new folders with chaotic jpg,sql,doc,txt and doc files

Tags: malware, windows

I found several new folders, each containing 10 small files with random content ( a chaotic picture, an rtf of random letters, a corrupted doc file etc...), all the files were created at the same time, owned by administrators, and accessed later.
Comodo scan found no threat and I couldn't find any info about this.

The file names are weird like proposed somebody sang.xls or goldenuse.mdb.

Any idea what's this and what can be done about it?

Edit:
The small files are safe according to Virustotal and Comodo.
Nothing happened for 3 days.

If it's a ransomware can I install a clean Windows in one partition and work there or should I format all the HD?

Comment: Looks like you got hit by ransomware. The note will ask for a payment, usually in Bitcoin, for the decrypting program. Restore your files from the backups if you have one.

Comment: Try to upload one file to virustotal and see if it gets flagged by a malware engine